# How to open IOS Linkedin Learning App from my app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an IOS application. Now, form my IOS application I wanna open https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/linkedin-learning/id1084807225?mt=8 app when it is installed or open itunes if not installed.

Comment: The target app needs to have a custom URL scheme. If it does, you can check see if you can open that URL. IF so, open it, if not, open the iTunes URL. If LinkedIn doesn't support a custom URL scheme, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must know if the LinkedIn application has deep linking.
Searching on [google](https://pureoxygenlabs.com/10-app-url-schemes-for-marketers/) I've found that linkedin exposes this custom url scheme `linkedin://`.
To open this application is just a matter of calling:

```
        if let url = URL(string: "linkedin://") , UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (open) in
                // Do something
            })
        } else {
            // DO somthing
        }
```

To first check is to be sure that you have a valid URL and the second to check if the app is installed, else it's up to you.

Comment: Its linkedin learning not linkedin

Comment: My bad, I've searched but still didn't find a specific url scheme, it's worth to try "linkedin-learning://". But if this app doesn't expose a sort of scheme is impossible to launch it.

Comment: I'm thinking that since application URL scheme are exposed inside the application info.plist and since this file is not cyphered, you can download the ipa and search into it for that file. Once you open it the key is `CFBundleURLSchemes`